# Athena queries returning quotes in values

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file with data that looks like `"John Doe",Washington,100,22,...`. The values that have quotes around them are the ones that contain whitespace. The values that don't have quotes don't have whitespace. The data has been processed by an AWS Glue Crawler, and when queried by AWS Athena, it returns all values, including the quotes. I don't want the quotes returned in my queries. I've tried looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-csv to try and fix this problem. However, that method only works if all values in the CSV contain quotes around them. Is there any way to fix this problem?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `weatherdata_output`(
  `name` string, 
  `state` string, 
  `lat` double, 
  `lng` double,
  ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://<bucket>/output'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1630559293')
```

Comment: Can you show us the DDL that defines the table? You can get it from Athena by clicking the 3-dots next to the table name and selecting **Generate Create Table DDL**. I'm mostly interested in seeing the configuration _below_ the column names. Please Edit your question and include that information. (Feel free to remove private content, such as the bucket name.)

Comment: I updated the question with the DDL.

Comment: I don't see escapechar and quotechar serde specified in your DDL. Replace ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' with ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escapeChar'='\\', 'quoteChar'='\"', 'seperatorChar'=',') n see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

To test your situation, I uploaded this data file:

```
"John Doe",Washington,100,22
"Peter Smith",Sydney,200,88
"Mary Moss",Tokyo,300,44
```

I then raw the Glue crawler, and it gave a similar DDL to yours. When I queried the data, it also had the problem with include quotation marks in the first column.

I then ran this command instead:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `city2`(
  `col0` string, 
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` bigint, 
  `col3` bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/city/'
```

Then, when I queried the table, it came out correctly:

[image: Athena query results]

Therefore, I would recommend using `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'` as the table format.

Comment: My only problem with this solution is that I'd have to manually add all the columns. I've got a lot of columns, and this would be very tedious and prone to error. Is there a way so that I don't have to write our all the column names?

Comment: Take the DDL that you got from Glue, and just change the ending. You can create a test table in Athena without changing/replacing your existing table -- just use a different table name in the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: For some of my columns, I get the error: [ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:DATA_ERROR], Detail:HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '<column>' for field 2: For input string: "<column>"

Comment: Please post your new DDL for the table, and a sample of the data (if it is different to what i used) so that we can reproduce the situation.

Comment: This error seems to go away when I add this to the DDL: TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1'). But then I get this error: [ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:DATA_ERROR], Detail:HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '' for field 4: For input string: "". I assume this is because some of my rows contain null values in the csv.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show your DDL, the error message and some sample data that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I ran your DDL against my sample file (above) and it worked fine. What if you remove the `OUTPUTFORMAT`? Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up dealing with the peculiarities of AWS Glue Crawler's CSV deserializer(s), and other schema-less file formats as well.

Instead, I prefer to convert the CSV (or other file formats) datasets into Parquet first - it's very simple to do so, for example via this simple Python script:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',', dtype=str)
df.info()  # Print the autodetected schema for verification and further tuning
print(df.head(30))  # Print a sample of dataframe records, for verification
print(f"records count = {df.count()}")

df.to_parquet('dataset.parquet')
```

This way I can have full control of my schema and even enforce a custom schema if not happy with Pandas's autodetected one. As a bonus, Parquet is faster for querying than CSV. Avro and ORC are good alternatives too, each one is better optimized for a specific use case (for example, columnar vs row data access). Most importantly, all of these formats support embedding the schema inside the file itself, unlike CSV and similar dumb plain file formats.

CSV files (and other schema-less file formats) should really burn in hell and never be used for data exchange purposes :-)

Make your life easier and simpler and just switch to a smarter format which supports embedded schemas, such as Parquet, ORC, or Avro. Glue Crawlers work perfectly with all of those, and you'll save yourself lots of time and quite a few headaches.