# why is AWS Athena adding quotes when I create CSV from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a CSV in AWS S3 with data that does not contain any quotes. But double quotes are added when I CREATE TABLE.

How do I suppress quotes in the output table fields?

This is the DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prod_users` (
  `user_id` string,
  `name` string,
  `birth_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ',') 
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/folder/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Comment: Try `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'`

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 missing EOF at 'WITH' near ')'

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008245/athena-queries-returning-quotes-in-values